# C++ OpenGL gluLookAt help

Tags: c++, opengl

I have been attempting to use gluLookAt but i have come across some issues...my first is what is the default position of the camera, whenever i try to use it, my whole scene seems to rotate sideways and up....
my second question is....from what i have read it is gluLookAt(Posx,Posy,PosZ,yaw,pitch,roll,then three up vectors)

but what order is yaw pitch and roll suppose to be in?

**Solved**
the default position of the camera is at gluLookAt(0, 0, 0, 0, 0,-1, 0, 1, 0); 
Thanks Drew for all your help :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have gotten some bad information about the arguments to gluLookAt().  From the OpenGL 2.1 [online documentation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/), the arguments should be as follows:

```
eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ:
  World coordinates of camera location

centerX, centerY, centerZ:
  World coordinates of camera aimpoint (what it's looking at).
  This point will be in the center of the resulting image, assuming
  that it lies between the near & far clip planes.

upX, upY, upZ:
  A vector (preferrably orthogonal to the line of sight) that specifies the
  roll orientation of the camera (that is, which way is "up" in the image).
```

As you can see, there is no explicit mention of pitch, roll, or yaw.

Also, by default, the camera is at (0, 0, -1) if I recall correctly--but it doesn't matter since you'll almost always call gluLookAt with the modelview matrix set to the identity.

Comment: ahhh -1...but what is meant by center?? sorry im really new to openGL

Comment: @|Phantasm|:  I tried to make that clear.  It's the point at which the camera is looking.  center - eye is thus the line-of-sight vector.

Comment: There is no camera in OpenGL. Period. And with no camera in OpenGL, there is no default camera position (0,0,-1). What actually happens is, that you have a matrix that transforms coordinates in the world space, called the modelview. Any movement of a camera can be also seen as an opposite movement of the whole world. gluLookAt applied such an opposite transformation on current modelview. So usually one first resets modelview to identity, which would place any kind of camera at the **origin** (0,0,0).

Comment: @datenwolf:  I know there is no "camera", and I understand how the modelview matrix works.  Nonetheless, we still (you included) colloquially refer to the action of gluLookAt as "moving the camera".  Default camera position would of course really mean "default value of the MV matrix", and sorry if my memory of that is a bit rusty.  As I said, you'll generally call gluLookAt() after loading the identity into MV which would eliminate the effects of any kind of default anyways.